# Windows 7 DNS lookups failing and fixing themselves

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, ping

I have one user who is sporadically unable to complete internal DNS queries and the problem fixes itself within 2-10 minutes and this problem has been lingering on for a couple months.  I haven't been able to see why it's occurring. Windows event log doesn't show anything. There was another user who logged the problem but it only happened once for him. When it happens to the one user no one else reports the problem and it would be obvious.

Steps taken:

- I've changed his DNS server from being the local one assigned via DHCP to another DNS server used at another location but the problem continues.
- Updated NIC
- Flush DNS

I made a simple bat to log pings when he has the problem.

- ping server1 by hostname (result could not find host server1)
- ping server1 by IP (result all pings successful)
- ping server2 by hostname (attempts to ping public IP instead of private not successsful but it wouldn't respond to ping on public IP anyway)
- ping server2 by private IP (result all pings successful)

Is my only recourse given it's intermittent nature a constant packet capture on his PC?

Comment: I would check if you can ping the DNS server during the failures (add it to your batch file). If you can't, the failure reported could be a clue: `Host Not Found` potentially being a routing issue while a `timeout` or `no response` result from the ping indicates a possible physical layer issue (or routing, but less likely).

Comment: I can ping the DNS server during the failures but nothing internally by name.

Comment: If you are running a server version of windows there are a number of guides online to logging all dns queries; if its a consumer version you have fewer options but you had already alluded ti it - wireshark.  You are describing an environment with a lot of relatively undefined components, and so its difficult, at least for me, to provide more specific advice.